# Parse shell file output with Python

Tags: python

I have a file with data. The file is the output generated from a shell scripting file:

```
|a                     |869         |
|b                     |835         |
|c                     |0           |
|d                     |0           |
|e                     |34          |
|f                     |3337
```

How can I get a = 869 from this?

Comment: Better title: how to read (or parse) columnar data file in Python?

Answer (score 9):

You could do this:

```
output = {}
for line in open("myfile"):
    parts = line.split('|')
    output[parts[1].strip()] = parts[2].strip()

print output['a'] // prints 869
print output['f'] // prints 3337
```

Or, using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module, as suggested by Eugene Morozov:

```
import csv
output = {}
reader = csv.reader(open("C:/output.txt"), delimiter='|')
for line in reader:
    output[line[1].strip()] = line[2].strip()

print output['a'] // prints 869
print output['f'] // prints 3337
```

Comment: I think it is better to construct a dictionary from the list of pairs. This way it is just one line and is doable with list comprehensions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751557/parse-shell-file-output-with-python/751613#751613

Comment: Personally I'm not a big fan of golfing every problem. Maybe it's because I'm new with Python but list comprehensions don't scream "beauty" to me like they apparently do to everyone.

Comment: Sure, it is a matter of taste. I find it more clear and local (I don't have to care if dict is empty or not).

Answer (score 4):

```
lines =  file("test.txt").readlines()
d = dict([[i.strip() for i in l.split("|")[1:3]] for l in lines if l.strip()])
```

For example:

```
>>> lines =  file("test.txt").readlines()
>>> d = dict([[i.strip() for i in l.split("|")[1:3]] for l in lines if l.strip()])
>>> d['a']
'869'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module with delimiter `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most Pythonic way, but this should work if your shell output is stored in f.txt and you are looking for every line to be processed:

```
h = open("f.txt", "rt")
inp = h.readline()
while inp:
  flds = inp.split('|')
  str = flds[1].strip() + " = " + flds[2].strip()
  print str
  inp = h.readline()
```